# Calling method directly without instance variable

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to call directly a method without creating instance of specific class like it is in C# so apart from that way:

```
Dim myclass as New ClassX
myclass.MyMethod()
```

is there a way to use soemthing like:

```
New ClassX.MyMethod
```

i found this way and seems to be working but not sure if its correct:

```
   (New ClassX).MyMethod
```

Answer (score 5):

If your method is an instance-level method you can only access it by using an instance of the class. By using

```
(New ClassX).MyMethod
```

you implicitly create a new instance that you access only once.

An alternative is to change the method's signature and mark it as a `Shared` method:

```
Public Class ClassX
    Public Shared Sub MyMethod()
        ' ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

`Shared` is the VB.NET way of creating a `static` method as it is called in C#. This way, you can access the method by only specifying the class name without creating an instance:

```
ClassX.MyMethod()
```

Comment: hi i was not talking about shared - i was talking not shared class (sorry should mentioned). Ok so in case non shared class it is correct to use this convence right?: (New ClassX).MyMethod

Comment: Please note that the class itself is not `Shared`. It is just the specific method that is `Shared`. So you can call this method without creating an instance, but not the others that are not `Shared`. Of course it is ok to use `(New ClassX).MyMethod` if required, but it is that done seldom. If it is a widely used case to call `MyMethod` without having an instance, I'd mark the method `Shared`.